# How can I get a BarLegend for ImageDisplacements?

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to compute Optical flow using [ImageDisplacements](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageDisplacements.html).In the example given in the documentation, there is a figure showing the levels of displacement. How can I get a Barlegend or something similar to show which colour represents what?